# Не запускается Apache при отключении от сети

Tags: apache, сервер, linux

Установил и запустил на Linux веб-сервер (и свой сайт).Все работало корректно пока не отключил сетевой шнур.Без сети Ahache не запускается.Можете дать пошаговую инструкцию по идентификации проблемы и ее устранению?

Comment: Смотрите лог индейца. Ошибки запуска в студию

Comment: For paytak:Когда Apache работает с сетью в конфиге прописано:                   Listen 0.0.0.0:80                                                  А без сети эта строка вызывает ошибку и замена адреса на 127.0.0.1:80 тоже вызывает ошибку

Comment: For gurzufnet:При попытке загрузить Apache с отключенным сетевым шнуром получаем:# /etc/init.d/httpd startStarting httpd: [Fri Sep 14 17:38:36 2012] [crit] (EAI 9)Address family for hostname not supported: alloc_listener: failed to set up sockaddr for 0.0.0.0Syntax error on line 181 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:Listen setup failed                                                                [ СБОЙ ]строка 181: Listen 0.0.0.0:80Хотя с этими настройками при включенной сети загрузка происходит без проблем

Comment: For gurzufnet:                                       Меняем адрес 0.0.0.0, который недоступен,на 127.0.0.1Получаем: /etc/init.d/httpd startStarting httpd: [Fri Sep 14 17:48:09 2012] [crit] (EAI 9)Address family for hostname not supported: alloc_listener: failed to set up sockaddr for 127.0.0.1Syntax error on line 181 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:Listen setup failed

Comment: For pyatak:Как здесь загрузить файлы ?Логи и конфиг большие, писать сюда замучаешься...

Answer (score 1):

Инструкция:

1. Вставьте сетевой кабель.

И вам вопрос, а нафига вам веб-сервер без сети? Допустим есть объективные тому причины. Wanga mode on. Apache скорее всего не страртует по причине того, что в конфиге указан адрес на который нужно биндиться, а так как, скорее всего адрес получаете по dhcp, при выключенном кабеле, этого адреса на интерфейсе нет, вот вам и fail.

Comment: "Нафига сервер без сети" - мне нужно запустить программу, написанную на PHP, там где нет доступа к сети (иначе я бы просто запускал ее со своего сайта). Почему не работает - у меня тоже есть некоторые догадки, но как их проверить и (главное) заставить работать?! В интернете есть отрывочные сведения на этот вопрос, но эти полумеры результатов не дали.Например, почему выдается ошибка на строку Listen 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: > ifconfig loв студию!

Comment: # ifconfig lolo Link encap:Local Loopback   inet addr:127..0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0   inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host   UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1   RX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0   TX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0   collisions:0 txqueuelen:0   RX bytes:15172 (14.8 KiB) TX  bytes:15172 (14.8 KiB)

Comment: Еще директива ServerType standalone тоже дает ошибку...

Comment: > inet addr:127..0.0.1  Как то в глаза бросается, попробуйте ка > ping 127.0.0.1

Comment: извините, лишняя точка - просто ошибка при наборе ответаадрес пингуется:                                        PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.          64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms

Comment: Давайте тогда логи, error логи, полностью сообщение о ошибке, вообщем все все все, да и конфиг в том числе.

Comment: А на каком адресе и порте httpd сетку слушает? Проверить можно так:sudo netstat -tunlp | grep httpd

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте поменять listen 0.0.0.0:80 на listen 80. И в /etc/hosts должно быть как то так 127.0.0.1 localhost. В общем индейцу нужен сетевой интерфейс, вот и подсуньте ему lo вместо eth.

Comment: Вопрос решил!!!                                 заменил 0.0.0.0 на [::] и все запустилось                   Огромное спасибо всем, кто откликнулся на мою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

мож кому пригодится:Чтобы при отключенном кабеле интерфейс остался, в разделе HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters реестра параметр DisableDHCPMediaSense (тип REG_DWORD) нужно установить = "1".

Comment: Тут, как бы, всё про *никсы...